# Jest Unit Tests: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" PushNotificationsIOS

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest, react-native-push-notification

Getting this error when running a snapshot test in jest for a component that imports PushNotificationsIOS.

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",






import {NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules} from 'react-native';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { Platform, AppState, Alert } from 'react-native';
    > 2 | import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by mocking PushNotificationIOS in our *mocks*.setUpTest.js file:

```
jest.mock('@react-native-community/push-notification-ios', () => ({
  checkPermissions: jest.fn(),
  requestPermissions: jest.fn(),
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  addNotificationRequest: jest.fn(),
  cancelLocalNotifications: jest.fn(),
}));
```